# trix editor image alignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trix

I have a blog site and am using the trix editor but I would like to have the images float either left or right and have the text wrap around them.  I have searched all over looking for a solution and cannot imagine why image alignment is not included.  I'm sure it is possible with css but but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: It isn't included because this has do to with messing a lot with the HTML and Trix editor is basic.  I think you will likely need to use a different editor to achieve this easily.  I'm not even sure if you could do it with CSS.

Comment: That’s what I was afraid of.  Thanks.

Comment: There are a lot of others out there.  CKEditor is one I use quite a bit and is probably more in line with what you would want.  But I would look into it and find a good tutorial and go from there.  Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks, CKEditor is what I was thinking I would try.

Comment: If it helps, last time I set this up I took some notes, it *might help you get it moving, otherwise I am sure there are tons of good blog posts, https://evening-brushlands-27438.herokuapp.com/posts/ckeditor-with-ruby-on-rails-5

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm trying to get it working but I'm using rails 6 and I cannot figure out how to set it up.

Comment: oh ya that is going to use webpacker, gonna be quite different I would search for a blog post on that, best of luck!

Comment: I actually got ckeditor working except that when I try to attach an image it doesn't show up in the text field and I cannot seem to change the size of the editor.

Comment: ya, I mean you will need to find a way to get it set up to work with active storage.  This may help (haven't tried)? https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/795 . Doesn't look good but possible solution

Answer (score 0):

Trix 1.3.1 doesn't support this, but there is an open PR, https://github.com/basecamp/trix/pull/791 (May 2020)

One commenter published a fork of trix that adds align-center and align-right buttons to the toolbar.